# System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource vs System.Diagnostics.Trace

Tags: c#, etw

I'm not sure I understand the major differences between ETW using System.Diagnostics.Tracing, and using System.Diagnostics.Trace. I understand that with both of them I can dump events onto some output stream, and that I can use various listeners to intercept this data - including custom listeners.

But except the fact that ETW's infrastructure is embdded into Windows and I can use WPR and PerfView out of the box, I don't see a difference.

When would I choose one over the other?

Comment: I am not sure you can use either to consume events. AFAIK you can only produce events, unless you're willing to P/Invoke the unmanaged ETW API.

Comment: Well, you can add Trace Listeners (including custom ones) to App.Config to consume events from System.Diagnostics.Tracing. About ETW - I'm pretty sure I saw tutorials on writing custom consumers, but I can surely use PerfView, etc.

Comment: My bad, sorry. I mistook the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` class for a different namespace and thus misunderstood your question.

Comment: My current understanding is that you would use ETW to log lower-level events (memory allocations, I/O accesses, etc.) in performance-critical situations, or when you need real-time logging. ETW is apparently very fast. `System.Diagnostics.Trace` et al. are a .NET-specific mechanism, not as fast, and perhaps more suited for logging higher-level application-specific events, e.g. that an admin might use to debug an application's configuration. I realise that is all rather vague. But it's as much as I know. Great question!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @stakx ETW is fast **given the set of features it supports**. For simple string logging inside of a process, I doubt it's faster than `Trace`. It would be worth testing though

Comment: @user884248: I believe I mixed up `System.Diagnostics.Trace` with `System.Diagnostics.Eventing`, the latter of which appears to also be an ETW-related namespace (like `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`), which is what I find quite confusing. Why does .NET have two namespaces that target the same Windows subsystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Diagnostics.Tracing` is much more complete than `Trace`:

- Events are segregated by event source, meaning that you don't have to subscribe to all events (good for performance)
- Inside of a source, events are segregated by name and "EventLevel", meaning that you can filter some more
- Events are structured (they're not just a string, they can also have payloads to give more information)

On the other hand, `System.Diagnostic.Trace` is a straightforward logger: you can only log strings, and you cannot apply any kind of filtering (it is either enabled for all messages, or disabled for all). But it has the advantage of being supported per default by the Visual Studio debugger (so when you attach to the process, you directly see trace events in the output window).

I'd add that having an ETW listener provided out of the box is a nice perk of `System.Diagnostics.Tracing`, but technically nothing would prevent you from writing your own ETW listener for `Trace`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - great answer!

Comment: This is all correct when you compare ETW against the static `Trace` class. There's sth. that falls somewhere between these two: `System.Diagnostics.TraceSource`. These are somewhat similar to ETW providers; they allow you to log objects, too, not just strings. Then there are trace levels and switches that allow you to filter events. `TraceSource` vs. ETW would probably be the fairer comparison (because they are more similar in feature completeness) than `Trace` vs ETW... but that's not a critique of your answer, just a suggestion.